# Android: How to unicast an intent to an Activity with inner BroadCastReceiver?

Tags: android

I have 2 Activities that need to communicate with each other: `ActivityA` and `ActivityB`

Say that ActivityA opens ActivityB. How do I unicast a message from `ActivityB` to `ActivityA` without closing ActivityB?

**Here's what I tried:**

1. setResult() - but the intent will
   be delivered only when ActivityB
   closes
2. sendBroadcast() - but this sends the
       intent to everyone listening to the
       action. I only want the action to
       reach `ActivityA` since it spawned
       `ActivityB`. I tried having ActivityA
       registering a BroadCast receiver,
       but I cannot target that via
       Intent's `SetComponentName()`.
3. startActivity() - this brings up
       ActivityA, which I don't want

Answer (score 1):

> I have 2 Activities that need to communicate with each other: ActivityA and ActivityB

You *think* they need to communicate with each other. I'd argue that, other than `startActivityForResult()`/`setResult()` pattern, ActivityB should not be communicating with ActivityA. Instead, they should be working through something else (e.g., service) that represents your model.

> How do I unicast a message from ActivityB to ActivityA without closing ActivityB?

Use your option #2 and `setPackage()` to constrain the delivery.